# Execute java methodes via a Python or Perl client

Tags: java, python, perl, client

I have a java application as server (installed on Tomcat/Apache) and another java application as client. The client's task is to get some arguments and pass them to the server and call an adequate method on the server to be execute.

I want to have the client in other languages like Perl, Python or TCL. So, I‌ need to know how to establish the communication and what is the communication structure. I'm not seeking for some codes but rather to know more about how to execute some java codes via other languages. I try to google it, but I mostly found the specific question/answer and not a tutorial or something like that. I wonder if I should search for a specific expression ? Do you know any tutorial or site whom explains such structures considering all aspects ?
Many thanks
Bye.

Comment: perl Inline::Java http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Java/Java.pod

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is Web Services. A corollary to this is XML and SOAP. In Java, Python, C#, C++... any language, you can create a Web Service that conforms to a standard pattern. Using NetBeans (Oracle's Java IDE) it is easy to create Java web services. Otherwise, use google to search for "web services tutorial [your programming language]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I gonna look for the web services. Just to be clear, Ithe java application exists todays and is currently used on tomcat. What I need to do is to see how I can have the client in other languages.

Comment: If someone were to update the wikipedia page on web services to explain what they are more clearly and with less jargon that would be great.  kthx. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service